# Jackson Json string deserialize class with HashMap member

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a problem regarding JSON deserialization. I have a class like this:

```
public class MapHolder
{
    HashMap<String,Integer> map1;
    HashMap<String,MyObject> map2
    HashMap<Integer, String> map3;
}
```

If I serialize this class into Json using Jackson and Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/state", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String state() throws Exception 
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(this.mapHolder);
}
```

It works and produces some Json like:

```
{
    "map1": [
    { ...
    "map2": [
    { ...
}
```

But when I want produced Json string to be deserialized back to MapHolder,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.readValue(json, MapHolder.class);
```

it crashes. Can anyone tell me what should I do to solve it?

Thank you,

Josef

Comment: And by "crashes" you mean... an exception? If so, what is the message?

Comment: Could you please provide a stack trace?

Comment: Exception is this:

e = (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class app.conn.mock.client.StateImpl

Comment: I also need to say, that I also used MyObjectInterface instead of MyObjectImpl and used this construct to make it possible:

    objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(); objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);

But it didn't work.

Comment: Enabling default typing may lead to mismatch, and you should not really need it either for simple case of abstract/concrete type. Instead, you can register a mapping between abstract and concrete type, using `SimpleModule`.

Comment: @StaxMan thank you. You've hit the point. I've used SimpleModule and mapped interfaces to their implementations. Deserializer started to work as if I have waved magic wand.

Comment: @JosefBureš good! Another possibility that also works is to specify `@JsonDeserialize(as=ImplType.class)`, but only works if you can modify abstract types in question.